# TFS 2015 vNext - selectively execute automated tests - need MTM?

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, tfs-2015, mtm

I'm building new automation infrastructure and have the privilege to use TFS 2015 vNext from the very first beginning. And so I did and defined my vNext build as part of my CI.

I just cannot find a way that a QA person or Dev person can selectively choose which automated test to run (what ever may be the reason for doing that) on any of the machines in the machines group. 
I would expect to have such functionality under the TEST hub but there isn't.

Am I missing something? 
Do I still have to use MTM for that and define XAML build, controller etc?
Any way to combine the two? 
I understood that Microsoft is about to abandon Lab Center (and the entire MTM) so what is the other option?

(I'm familiar with "[Executing Automated tests in Build vNext using Test Plan, Test Suites](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/31/executing-automated-tests-in-build-vnext-using-test-plan-test-suites/)" but would like to give the freedom to select tests).

[Lab Management Evolution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/08/26/lab-management-evolution/)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean you just want to customize  the running order of the automated tests  or  random select even only run some of the automates tests like the manually test?

Comment: select manually which automated tests to run on one of the target (testing) machines. 
The idea is to let QA or Dev to run sub-set of the automation, on demand, whenever they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any way to select tests from Run Functional Tests steps, I have help you submit a feature request on VSTS/TFS User Voice, you can vote it here: [Allow to select test case in "Run Functional Tests" step](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/15953482-allow-to-select-test-case-in-run-functional-tests).

The work around for now would be create one suite for each test so that you can choose in the build definition.

Or you can also use test filter criteria to run selective test, refer to this link for details: [Running selective unit tests in VS 2012 using TestCaseFilter](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/09/26/running-selective-unit-tests-in-vs-2012-using-testcasefilter/).

Comment: Wouldn't this require permission to actually modify a build/release definition? I don't think we want everyone to just modify the build/release definition. 
We do have this need as well, and I think something like this would do it for us: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub. However, this feature is available in VSTS only. When will it be available to on-prem TFS?